# Breadcrumb doesn't work on a component I created (Joomla!)

Tags: breadcrumbs, joomla3.2

I'm learning how to use Joomla! 3.2

I created a new component, then I added it to my main menu,

Here are the only parameters I changed in the main menu:
[image: parameters]

But now when I go to my new component the breadcrumb doesn't work correctly, there's only the home button and when I click on it I'm redirected to the same page:

[image: breadcrumb]

Did i missed something very important? How can I fix it? The breadcrumb works on every other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the problem, I forgot to add this

```
$pathway = $app->getPathway();
$breadcrumb = $pathway->setPathway(array());
$pathway->addItem( JText::_( 'COM_PARTISPOLITIQUES' ),JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_partispolitiques&view=partispolitique'));
$pathway->addItem( "Current page name",'');
```

In the file `view.html.php` located in my component folder...

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you are using the Helix template as it seems to be a common oversight.

Make sure that Enable Page Title is enabled from your menu Helix Page Title tab.
If not, please advise as to what template.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I actually use a home-made template created by a former trainee.

Comment: Do you have a link we can view?

Comment: I am going to throw this out there because oddly it has fixed a few peoples problems in the last 24 hours. :/  turn "Search Engine Friendly URLs and Use URL Rewriting" off.

Navigate the site on the frontend, to the area affected.

Then turn "Search Engine Friendly URLs and Use URL Rewriting" on.

Comment: norcal johnny I tried it but it doesn't work :/ (when I disable SEF my content doesn't display anymore, i have a blank page) and I can't show you the website because I work on localhost.

Comment: Is your htaccess file a .htaccess or htaccess.txt and are you on a linux machine?

Comment: It's a .txt file and I use Windows 7